Auth::check() return false when redirecting - Laravel
First, i have login controller like this
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\User\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\User\Auth\Login\First;
use App\Http\Requests\User\Auth\Login\Second;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class Login extends Controller
{
    public function Interface()
    {
        if(!Session::get('login.section'))
        Session::put('login.section', 'first');
        if(Session::get('login.section') == 'first')
        return self::FirstInterface();
        else if(Session::get('login.section') == 'second')
        return self::SecondInterface();
    }
    public function Action(First $first_request, Second $second_request)
    {
        if(Session::get('login.section') == 'first')
        return self::FirstAction($first_request);
        else if(Session::get('login.section') == 'second')
        return self::SecondAction($second_request);
    }
    public function FirstInterface()
    {
        return Inertia::render('User/Auth/Login/First');
    }
    public function FirstAction(First $request)
    {
        Session::put('login.email', $request -> email);
        $user = User::where('email', $request -> email) -> first();
        if($user)
        {
            Session::put('login.name', $user -> name);
            Session::put('login.section', 'second');
            return redirect('login');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('login')
            -> with('error', 'Email unregistered');
        }
    }
    public function SecondInterface()
    {
        return Inertia::render('User/Auth/Login/Second');
    }
    public function SecondAction(Second $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', Session::get('login.email')) -> first();
        if(Hash::check($request -> password, $user -> password))
        {
            Session::forget('login');
            Auth::login($user);
            return redirect('home');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('login')
            -> with('error', 'Login failed');
        }
    }
}

And i have route like this
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

if(Auth::check()) {
    Route::get('home', function() {
        return Inertia::render('home');
    })
    -> name('Home');
}
else {
    Route::prefix('/')
    -> group(base_path('routes/register.php'));

    Route::prefix('/')
    -> group(base_path('routes/login.php'));
}

When i try to login, i believe that Auth::login() already work, because when i add Auth::check in same function like this, Auth::check() return true and "Already Login" will appear
public function SecondAction(Second $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', Session::get('login.email')) -> first();
        if(Hash::check($request -> password, $user -> password))
        {
            Session::forget('login');
            Auth::login($user);
            if (Auth::check())
            {
                dd('Already Login');
            }
            return redirect('home');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('login')
            -> with('error', 'Login failed');
        }
    }

But, when i redirect into '/home', Auth::check() in my route always return false
How can i fix that?

use middleware instead of implementing login into router file.

use like
-> middleware('auth')?

Yes, Also if you want some other functionality along with auth you can also build a custom middleware.

nice! it works!, but, when i use middleware, how can I use route::redirect('home', 'login') when user didn't login?

which version of laravel you are using ?

i use laravel 11

You want when a user is not authenticated that user should be redirected to login page.right?
